# How manage history version of entities with Entity Framework Core 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I got a model like below which is having some related tables associated with this like Addresses, MetaInfo, etc :

```cs
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [MaxLength(15)]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    ......some more string and int properties

    public virtual ICollection<ContactAddress> Addresses { get; set; }

    public virtual ContactMetaInfo MetaInfo { get; set; } 
}
```

```cs
public class ContactAddress
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Contact))]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public virtual  Contact Contact { get; set; } 

    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Line1 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Line2 { get; set; }

    ......some more string and int properties and some foreign keys 

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Continent))]
    public int? ContinentId { get; set; }

    public virtual  Continent Continent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Country))]
    public int? CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual  Country Country { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(County))]
    public int? CountyId { get; set; }

    public virtual  County County { get; set; } 
}
```

Now I am dealing with a requirement. I have to create a **historical version** of these entities.

I am thinking of making new Class as Entities like below :

- HistoryContact
- HistoryContactAddress
- HistoryContactMetaInfo

And copy all properties from Contact to HistoryContact and subsequent tables. There are almost 7 Entities are there to copy so...

In future, if a new property added to any of these entities, I have to handle them manually in 2 entities [Master and History entities separately].

Is any better way to handle these scenarios?

> Currently I'm using EF Core 5, but it's possible to use EF Core 6.

Comment: An alternate idea would be to generate audit logs which can log to files or to a database. For example, [Audit.NET library](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET).

Comment: One answer: AutoMapper.

Comment: If we use auto mapper, the migration will create the history tables for me?

Comment: If you can use audit instead of history, [this article can help](https://www.meziantou.net/entity-framework-core-history-audit-table.htm)

Comment: It's EF Core 5?

Comment: EF Core 5 , But if 6 provides some better options can update to EF core 6 as well

Comment: You have to add the classes to the EF entity model, but you can use AutoMapper to create one from the other. Other than that, EF and AM aren't related.

Comment: How familiar are you with Temporal Tables? (not to be confused with Temporary Tables)?

Comment: @Dai not very familiar with Temporal tables. Wondering can i use this with Mysql Since my primary database is mysql

Comment: [MariaDB has excellent support for Temporal Tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/temporal-tables/) (far better than MS SQL Server's). EF has support for Temporal Tables too, but only in EFCore 6+. If your only experience is with MySQL then switching to MariaDB is a breeze, you won't even notice the difference [as it's designed to be drop-in compatible](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-migrate-from-mysql-to-mariadb-on-linux-in-five-steps/) (MariaDB is a superior fork of MySQL).